# WHERE NOT EXISTS IN INSERT STATEMENT - POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to insert a row in the table with the select statement and using not exists conditions. if the
select statement record does not exist then insert the row. but I am getting an error. Can anyone please help on this

what am I trying is I need to select records which satisfies the condition and I need to insert if the doesn't exist in the table

```
INSERT INTO TBL_VPC_AT_CONS_INC_DE_DUP_01_BK_APR_14 (
  source_system_org, group_number,
  contact_party_id, Contact_Email,
  translated_contact_email, contact_last_update_date_ref,
  contact_relationship_id, contact_first_name,
  contact_last_name, partner_ref_party_id,
  contact_address_line1, contact_city,
  contact_state, contact_postal_code,
  contact_country, Contact_Part_name,
  deassociated_record, eloque_flag,
  modified_email,
  TO_BE_INSERTED
)
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      source_system_org,
      group_number,
      contact_party_id,
      Contact_Email,
      translated_contact_email,
      contact_last_update_date_ref,
      contact_relationship_id,
      contact_first_name,
      contact_last_name,
      partner_ref_party_id,
      contact_address_line1,
      contact_city,
      contact_state,
      contact_postal_code,
      contact_country,
      Contact_Part_name,
      deassociated_record,
      eloque_flag,
      modified_email,
      'Y' AS TO_BE_INSERTED
      FROM TBL_VPC_AT_CONS_INC_DE_DUP_01_BK_APR_14
      WHERE eloque_flag = 'S'
  )AA
  WHERE deassociated_record != 'Y'
) BB
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM (
                    SELECT * 
                    FROM (
                      SELECT source_system_org,
                             group_number,
                             contact_party_id,
                             Contact_Email,
                             translated_contact_email,
                             contact_last_update_date_ref,
                             contact_relationship_id,
                             contact_first_name,
                             contact_last_name,
                             partner_ref_party_id,
                             contact_address_line1,
                             contact_city,
                             contact_state,
                             contact_postal_code,
                             contact_country,
                             Contact_Part_name,
                             deassociated_record,
                             eloque_flag,
                             modified_email,
                             'Y' AS TO_BE_INSERTED
                      FROM TBL_VPC_AT_CONS_INC_DE_DUP_01_BK_APR_14
                      WHERE eloque_flag = 'S'
                    ) AA
                    WHERE deassociated_record != 'Y'
                  )B 
                  WHERE TBL_VPC_AT_CONS_INC_DE_DUP_01_BK_APR_14.TO_BE_INSERTED = B.TO_BE_INSERTED 
                    AND TBL_VPC_AT_CONS_INC_DE_DUP_01_BK_APR_14.source_system_org = B.source_system_org
                    AND TBL_VPC_AT_CONS_INC_DE_DUP_01_BK_APR_14.contact_party_id = B.contact_party_id);
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example. Get yourself acquainted with https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your query looks overly complicated and the same query is used in Select and Not Exists clause. As suggested, create a minimal reproducible example with only attributes used in join/conditions, with few rows of sample data and your expected output based on that sample data.

Comment: Why not use `insert ... on conflict do nothing` assuming you have a unique constraint (or index) on the columns that should be unique

Comment: what is the actual error that you get?

Comment: Note that your `select * from ( select * from (select .. from...)))` can easily be flattened into a single SELECT statement which will be a lot easier to read.